# Core Data: NSFetchRequest sorting by count of to-many relationship

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Say I have an parent entity, each of which have a number of children. I want to get all the parents sorted by their number of children. Something similar to the following pseudo code:

```
NSEntityDescription * entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Parent" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"children.count" ascending:NO];
//Execute request
```

Is there a way construct a fetch like this using core data? If there is no way to do this will sorting using `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` loose the benefits of _PFBatchFaultingArray  batch size?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query would work, but (assuming `children` is faulted) would use key-value coding methods on the `children` property, which in turn would fire the fault (see [the NSManagedObject docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject?language=objc) for a list of methods that fire faults, and a discussion of this behavior), so you'd lose the performance benefits of batching and faulting.

You might consider maintaining a derived attribute on your parent entity (call it `childrenCount`) that reflects the number of children related to the parent, if this is feasible for your situation. It's not the cleanest solution, but if you keep it as an NSNumber in the parent entity you'd have access to it even if `children` is faulted, and you can sort on it directly.

Comment: The KVC `@count` would be performed on the `NSSet` not the objects within that `NSSet` and therefore does not cause the faults to fire.

Comment: It does cause the fault to fire, since Core Data doesn't fault each object individually - it faults the set itself (or rather, a concrete subclass of NSSet). See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001202, under "Faulting Limits the Size of the Object Graph".

Comment: Are things changed ever since? iOS 7 throws exception for this type of sorting: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: @an0: are you using the key path from the original question? I think it needs to be `children.@count`, not `children.count`, as per Marcus's comment.

Comment: Tried that too. That's another except: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Keypath containing KVC aggregate where there shouldn't be one'

Comment: According to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839265/nssortdescriptor-with-to-many-relationship), this can't be done.

Comment: This looks like a limitation of the SQLite store type. I'm able to do this successfully using both an in-memory and a binary store, but the SQLite store throws the error you describe. See https://github.com/lithium3141/CoreDataCountTest for a sample app that demonstrates this behavior.

Comment: @Tim The docs link in your answer now goes nowhere. Do you remember which page in the docs it went to?

Comment: @future-adam thanks for the heads up. It was to the NSManagedObject class reference. I've updated the link to point at Apple's new documentation.