# NSSortDescriptor with to-many relationship

Tags: core-data

I have a Parent entity which has to-many Child. If I order the Parent fetch with a property (e.g. name), everything works fine. But if I try this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"child.@count" ascending:NO];
```

It doesn't work. I've also tried to add

```
[fetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"child"]]];
```

But it didn't work as well.

Am I allowed to sort by to-many.@count or do I need to add a property and update it each time I add a child?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you are using a sqlite store; you cannot sort by `@count` because it is resolved at the "object" level whereas the `NSSortDescriptor` on the `NSFetchRequest` is resolved at the database level.  Therefore, as you guessed, you would need to create a counting property to sort by.

If you are using a binary or in-memory store type then count should work fine since they are only accessed as objects.

Comment: Thank you. I was confused because it sounded like it was possible according to the answer you gave here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448252/core-data-nsfetchrequest-sorting-by-count-of-to-many-relationship