# Core Data - complex fetch

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

This is my core data model:

```
Conference
==========
name

events (to-many relationship to Event object)

Event
======
date
type (int - private=0, public=1)

conference (to-one relationship to Conference object)
```

So conference can have many events, and event has only one conference:

```
Conference <------>> Event
```

I have a complex fetch that I'm not sure how to do, this is what I need:

The 3 top conferences with the most public events AND meet the basic conditions, meaning:
1. conference has at least 1 private event.
2. conference has at least 5 public event.
3. should be calculated based on the last 10 days

I'm not sure if I should query the `Conference` objects directly or query the `Event` objects and than filter the appropriate conferences using event.conference

Efficiency is important, so if possible to use fetch limit or other optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SUBQUERY to do it in a single fetch request:

```
 NSDateComponents* components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [components setDay:[components day] - 10];
    NSDate* tenDaysAgo = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];

    NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Conference class])];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(events, $event, $event.type = 0 AND $event.date > %@).@count >= 1 AND SUBQUERY(events, $event, $event.type = 1 AND $event.date > %@).@count >= 5", tenDaysAgo, tenDaysAgo];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"events.count" ascending:NO];
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 3;
```

**NOTE**: sort descriptor with events.count will only work for in-memory store or binary store, but it will crash for SQLite store (more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839265/nssortdescriptor-with-to-many-relationship)). In this case you should sort and limit results after the fetch.

Comment: btw, the sort should be only according to the "public" events, do I need to filter the array before the sort? or is there more efficient way?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to do that with NSFetchRequest if you use SQLite store. You can sort the array after the fetch using method 'sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:comparator:' of `NSSortDescriptor`. Or you can add additional property `publicEventsCount` to your `Conference` entity and update it each time you add or remove an Event object to the Conference. You should be able to use this property for sorting with fetch request.