# How to do a complex fetch request in Core data

Tags: swift, sqlite, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have implemented Core data for storage in my App. I need to perform complex fetches using FetchRequest & predicate like below SQLite query:

```
SELECT
  diagnosis_drug.drug_id,
  diagnosis_drug.weight_bracket_id,
  score,
  localscore,
  (score + localscore) AS score,
  drug.*
FROM diagnosis_drug
INNER JOIN drug
  ON diagnosis_drug.drug_id = drug.id
WHERE diagnosis_drug.doctor_id = 3
AND diagnosis_id IN (29, 212)
AND score > 0
AND weight_bracket_id = 1
AND diagnosis_drug._d = 0
ORDER BY score DESC
```

here diagnosis_drug  & drug are entities and other are attributes.

```
Entity : Diagnosis_drug
Attributes : 
diagnosisId - Int32
doctorId - Int32
drugId - Int32
score - Int32
localScore - Int32

Entity : Drug.
Attributes :
id : Int32
dosage : Int32
volume : Int32
genericName : String
formulation : String
doseType : String
duration : Int32
name : String
```

Drug's "id" attribute is equal to Diagnosis_drug's "drugId" attribute. The query is to get top score drugs from Diagnosis_drug and inner join is made to Drug entity to get its details.

Comment: The only bit that’s going to cause difficulties is the computed `score`:  In CoreData you cannot sort a fetchrequest by a computed variable (you might also have problems with that bit of the predicate, too).  So the simplest solution will be to add an additional attribute for `totalscore` which you can then use to sort and filter.

Comment: @pbasdf Ok, Just ignoring the computation(i'll add the additional attribute as said), how can I create fetch request for this.

Comment: Please update your post with details of the entities and the relationships between them, and any code for what you’ve tried so far.

Comment: @pbasdf Have updated the qn. I was trying to do something by using <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968032/core-data-complex-fetch> but could find how to actually.

Comment: Have you implemented a relationship between the Diagnosis_drug and Drug entities?

Comment: No, there's no relation, both are different entities(No, one to one or one to many relation). Its just that by  Diagnosis_drug's "drugId" attribute we can relate to Drug's, "id" attribute to fetch its details.

Comment: OK, so that's the first step.  If you implement the releationships, and populate them when you create the objects, CD will manage the primary/foreign keys, table joins etc for you.  If you have complex joins/computed variables etc, you might do better using SQLite directly.

Comment: Thanks @pbasdf for the help. I have posted few of my findings as Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out there are few limitations to core data . You can perform fetchrequest on two different entities only when they have a Relation between them. viz. if you have one-to-one relation between a Person(entity_1) and his mobile(entity_2) , to fetch both we need to perform a fetch on Person entity . To set filter on Person we'll add a Predicate as we need and to set filter on mobile , we'll put a "SUBQUERY" on mobile attributes in same predicate. If the two entities dont have a relation , there's a work around. You make those two entities as sub-entity of a new Parent entity, and perform a fetch on the new Parent entity ( [See Reference](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-fetch-multiple-entities-with-an-nsfetchedresultscontroller/#comment-69184)! ). Still this leaves us with cases where those two entities already have some other Parents ! Here there is no relation as well as common Parent entity. So here is the limitation of Core data. You'll need to perform fetch on both such entities separately. Also Core data fetches don't allow computation inside query predicates(You'll need to maintain an extra variable in your entity and update that every time as you need). Any corrections on my findings are welcome . Thanks.