# How to filter & fetch records with MagicalRecord?

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I've two classes like this,

```
@class Songs;

@interface Album : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * albumID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *songs;

@end

@interface Album (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addSongsObject:(Songs *)value;
- (void)removeSongsObject:(Songs *)value;
- (void)addSongs:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeSongs:(NSSet *)values;
@end
@class Album;

@interface Songs : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * length;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Album *owner;

@end
```

Suppose, I've 10 albums created and each album have some random (positive) number of songs. Now I want to find & fetch top 5 albums which has the maximum number of songs.

How do I do that with MagicalRecords?

Currently, I'm doing it like this,

```
NSLog(@"%@",[Album MR_findAllSortedBy:@"albumID" ascending:YES withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"@max.@count.songs"]]);

//NSLog(@"%@",[Album MR_findAllSortedBy:@"albumID" ascending:YES]); //works fine
```

but its crashes with following message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format
>   string "@max.@count.songs"'

Is my predicate string invalid? If yes, what is the correct way to achieve this.

Comment: This isn't an answer so I'm writing it as a comment : I was not comfortable with magical records library I completely removed it from the app and doing everything on my own. I'm little slow with it, but learning & jumping is better then falling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839265/nssortdescriptor-with-to-many-relationship), you can not sort by count on fetch. You need to fetch all items and than sort and trim them:

```
 NSArray* array = [Album MR_findAll];
 array = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"songs.@count" ascending:NO] ] ];
 array = [array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, MIN( array.count, 5) )];
```